# How come UAC logs are not being stored in Event Viewer?

Tags: windows, group-policy, event-log, forensics

In Event Viewer, under Applications and Services Logs, UAC logs are not being stored. How do I enable them? Could Domain/OU group policy have them disabled? If so where can I see that it is disabled by group policy?

The reason I want to enable them is so I can see when a user runs Event Viewer as a different user, for example...
[image]

Comment: This is a Windows-specific config question and not an InfoSec question, even though there could be InfoSec implications.